# Anyone know of a "live" markup/comments/revision FireFox/Chrome extension?

Tags: web, editing

When I'm asked to do revisions on a Website, I usually have the non-technical editor print out pages in question with comments/revisions written in ink, but this obviously has it's drawbacks.

I was wondering if anyone was familiar with a Firefox/Chrome add-on/extension (thinking like a GreaseMonkey type script maybe) or an application that would allow a non-technical person to add comments/revisions to "live" pages, even if it was just typing over it or similar to how Word does it with the built-in collaboration feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, Google is your friend; can't believe I didn't see this before.

http://markup.io/